# OpenVAS: OSPD scanner can't be used as scanner in new task

Tags: openvas

After understanding how to add an ospd scanner, verify it etc ...
I though I could finally use it but got an error through UI to add it to a task.

In my case, I run OpenVAS 9 on a debian 9 and I'm trying to include a w3af scanner but I got the same issue with every OSP scanner I add.

my pip freeze :

```
ospd==1.2.0
ospd-debsecan==1.2b1
ospd-nmap==1.0b1
ospd-w3af==1.0.0
```

Note that here is an example of w3af but the issue is the same for debsecan scanner and nmap scanner.

my openvas-check-setup :

```
Step 1: Checking OpenVAS Scanner ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is present in version 5.1.1.
        OK: redis-server is present in version v=3.2.6.
        OK: scanner (kb_location setting) is configured properly using the redis-server socket: /tmp/redis.sock
        OK: redis-server is running and listening on socket: /tmp/redis.sock.
        OK: redis-server configuration is OK and redis-server is running.
        OK: NVT collection in /usr/local/var/lib/openvas/plugins contains 47727 NVTs.
        WARNING: Signature checking of NVTs is not enabled in OpenVAS Scanner.
        SUGGEST: Enable signature checking (see http://www.openvas.org/trusted-nvts.html).
        OK: The NVT cache in /usr/local/var/cache/openvas contains 47727 files for 47727 NVTs.
Step 2: Checking OpenVAS Manager ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is present in version 7.0.2.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database found in /usr/local/var/lib/openvas/mgr/tasks.db.
        OK: Access rights for the OpenVAS Manager database are correct.
        OK: sqlite3 found, extended checks of the OpenVAS Manager installation enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database is at revision 184.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager expects database at revision 184.
        OK: Database schema is up to date.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database contains information about 47727 NVTs.
        OK: At least one user exists.
        OK: OpenVAS SCAP database found in /usr/local/var/lib/openvas/scap-data/scap.db.
        OK: OpenVAS CERT database found in /usr/local/var/lib/openvas/cert-data/cert.db.
        OK: xsltproc found.
Step 3: Checking user configuration ... 
        WARNING: Your password policy is empty.
        SUGGEST: Edit the /usr/local/etc/openvas/pwpolicy.conf file to set a password policy.
Step 4: Checking Greenbone Security Assistant (GSA) ... 
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is present in version 7.0.2.
        OK: Your OpenVAS certificate infrastructure passed validation.
Step 5: Checking OpenVAS CLI ... 
        OK: OpenVAS CLI version 1.4.5.
Step 6: Checking Greenbone Security Desktop (GSD) ... 
        SKIP: Skipping check for Greenbone Security Desktop.
Step 7: Checking if OpenVAS services are up and running ... 
        OK: netstat found, extended checks of the OpenVAS services enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is running and listening on a Unix domain socket.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is running and listening on a Unix domain socket.
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is listening on port 443, which is the default port.
Step 8: Checking nmap installation ...
        WARNING: Your version of nmap is not fully supported: 7.40
        SUGGEST: You should install nmap 5.51 if you plan to use the nmap NSE NVTs.
Step 10: Checking presence of optional tools ...
        OK: pdflatex found.
        WARNING: PDF generation failed, most likely due to missing LaTeX packages. The PDF report format will not work.
        SUGGEST: Install required LaTeX packages.
        OK: ssh-keygen found, LSC credential generation for GNU/Linux targets is likely to work.
        OK: rpm found, LSC credential package generation for RPM based targets is likely to work.
        OK: alien found, LSC credential package generation for DEB based targets is likely to work.
        OK: nsis found, LSC credential package generation for Microsoft Windows targets is likely to work.
```

To create the scanner in openvas, I use:

```
openvasmd --create-scanner="w3af" --scanner-host=127.0.0.1 --scanner-port=1235 --scanner-type="OSP" \
--scanner-ca-pub=/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem \
--scanner-key-pub=/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem \
--scanner-key-priv=/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/private/CA/clientkey.pem
```

To run ospd-w3af scanner, I use:

```
~# ospd-w3af -b 127.0.0.1 -p 1235 -k \
/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/private/CA/clientkey.pem -c \
/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem --ca-file \
/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem -L DEBUG
```

When I verify the scanner with openvasmd --verify-scanner xxxxx I got

```
Scanner version: 2018.8.22.
```

note: in the logs of the scanner I got this for every verify I do, I don't know if it's related or no and I didn't find a way to fix this:

```
2018-10-15 14:27:47,413 ospd.ospd: DEBUG: New connection from 127.0.0.1:60078
2018-10-15 14:27:49,430 ospd.ospd: DEBUG: Error: ('The read operation timed out',)
2018-10-15 14:27:49,433 ospd.ospd: DEBUG: 127.0.0.1:60078: Connection closed
```

**So, my verification made, I want to create a task that uses this scanner but I can't save it due to error "Given scanner_type was invalid" :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvIJd.png

I got 0 connection to the chosen scanner at this moment and I can't find anything in the logs (maybe I can't search). I suspect the gsad UI being responsible for this but I can't find it.

I don't know what to do and if someone more expert than me (not very hard) could help that'd be great :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a scan configuration for the ospd scanner (I though it didn't need one since it import them)

I faced another issue concerning ospd-w3af configuration, I couldn't create one because it needs ospd 1.0.0 installed, I modified the dependencies few days ago and it doesn't work with ospd 1.2.0

Now I'm facing the issue where the scans doesn't start properly. It stops at 1%

Answer (score 0):

Getting openvas 9 running on new install of Ubuntu 18 was a pain. once i got past all my errors by creating files and ln -s for redis-server socks connections my tasks crapped out at 1%. My fix was install sudo apt install libopenvas-dev after that scans work and check-setup worked. Check-setup report no scanner but openvassd was running and openvasmd --verify-scanner (uuid) showed the scanner.